# Java JDBC resultSet.next issue

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

My resultSet is null

```
System.out.println("ResultSet :" +rs.next());
```

Output:

> ResultSet :false

But…

```
if(rs.next() == false) {//condition }
```

…returns an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:915)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:438)
at com.dxc.gameservices.dao.BadgesService.BadgeOne(BadgesService.java:33)
```

code:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from TABLE Where Column1=1 AND column2=4");
           if(rs.next() == false) {
               System.out.println("Inside IF");
           }
           else{
               System.out.println("Inside ELSE");
           }
```

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: What do you mean your ResultSet is null? If so, you would get a `NullPointerException` when calling *any* method such as `rs.getNext()`.

Comment: @BasilBourque update the code. could you please check.

Comment: Have you tried the same query in oracle database directly? And is there any such row in table which satisfies the exact conditions ??

Comment: The code you show cannot trigger this error. Please show the full code of method `BadgeOne`.

Answer (score 2):

This exception means you consume twice the same result :

> java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:915)
>   at

You don't show the code that does `getInt()` but you probably do something like :

```
rs.next();
int value = rs.getInt(index);
int anotherValue = rs.getInt(index);
```

You cannot. You consume twice the same row.

You have to invoke `next()` to retrieve the next row of the cursor :

```
while (rs.next()) {
   int value = rs.getInt(index);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Agree it cannot be twice. the result is the same even after commenting the SOP.

Comment: Most JDBC drivers are perfectly fine with using a `getXxx` on the same field multiple times. The only exception I'm aware of was the JDBC/ODBC bridge (which is why the JDBC api suggests to call getters only once per field per row). The problem - if I had to guess - would be that in the `if(rs.next() == false)`, the OP is calling `getInt` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
if (rs != null) {
  while (rs.next()) {
    …
  }
}
```

Comment: tried this but no luck. tried all types like rs.beforeFirst(), first and various suggested on other posts.

Comment: @PRABHAKARTHOTA This code is correct approach. You must edit your Question to give more info. Please study the JDBC tutorials at Oracle.com and study related Questions/Answers on Stack Overflow *before* posting.

Comment: Could you please check the code now. IT is a simple 4 lines. my select statement has no rows returned. The same is confirmed as rs.next() returning false.

Comment: tried the above code. result is Error: ResultSet.next was not called

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the line, System.out.println("ResultSet :" +rs.next()); before you trying to check in while, becuase the next element was already getting checked.

while (rs.next()) {
}

Comment: yes. tried. SOP was jus to confirm the values of rs.next() which is false.

Comment: have you tested the SQL query to check it returns the results?